# Calculating Range of a Function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I am doing problems in the chapter Functions. I have enclosed images of the question and my solution for the problem.

Question: (Kindly ignore the question code - [16JM120379])
[image: Question]
My Solution:

[image: Solution]

Clearly, there is no such option in the given question. So, did I go wrong anywhere? If yes, please tell where I went wrong. Or, is the question having a missing option?

Kindly guide me how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You incorrectly identified the domain of $h(x)$. If we have that
$$\cos{(x)}\in[-1,1/2]$$
Then there are infinitely many intervals in which $x$ can lie given by adding and subtracting $2\pi$ to the supplied interval. So you should instead have
$$\text{dom }h=[\pi/3+2\pi k,5\pi/3+2\pi k]_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$$
But you also made another mistake because you should then get
$$x+\pi/3\in[2\pi/3+2\pi k,2\pi+2\pi k]_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$$
where you added $\pi/3$ to $5\pi/3$ and somehow got $\pi$. One could continue to get
$$\sin{(x+\pi/3)}\in[-1,\sqrt{3}/2]$$
$$\arccos{(\sin{(x+\pi/3)})}\in[\pi/6,\pi]$$
$$\exp{(\arccos{(\sin{(x+\pi/3)})})}\in\left[e^{\pi/6},e^\pi\right]$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. The first mistake (not taking the general solution but just taking the principal solution) doesn't affect the final answer, right sir?

Comment: No, but I just want to make sure you know this in case of future questions.

Comment: Ok sir, understood. Thank you very much for your kind help.